# Counting security groups nested into other security groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to learn the scope of my companies security group nesting.  We have a lot of groups nested into others which is causing issues with security token size (IE adding User X to Group Y increases their group membership count by 350+).

I want generate a report that lists all security groups (while excluding distribution groups) and counts the total number of recursive group memberships.

Quest Tools can run on-demand reports without issue `"(get-qadgroup "GroupHere").AllMemberOf.count"`.  I'm having problems extracting everything into a report.  Here's what I'm trying.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {groupCategory -eq 'Security'} | 
Select SamAccountName |
ForEach-Object { (get-qadgroup $_.SamAccountName).AllMemberOf.count |
Export-csv -path "C:\_Reports\Security Group Nesting Numbers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -append
}
```

My logic behind the "-append" is to avoid a loop re-writing the top value. I'm not 100% sure it's necessary.

The Get-ADGroup works fine.  The Select works fine.  The ForEach does return a list of numbers.  I think they're accurate.  I'm mainly having trouble exporting the SamAccountName with the associated `AllMemberOf.Count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
#Create array to hold all groups
$groups = @()
#Run through groups
Get-ADGroup -Filter {groupCategory -eq 'Security'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {
    #Get current group
    $currentGroup = Get-ADGroup $_
    #Create new custom object
    $group = New-Object System.Object
    #Add group info to custom object
    $group | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SamAccountName" -Value $currentGroup.SamAccountName
    $group | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Count" -Value $currentGroup.AllMemberOf.Count
    #Add custom object to array
    $groups += $group
}
#Output array to CSV
$groups | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\test.csv
```

The output in the CSV file looks like this:

```
SamAccountName         Count
Group1                 2
Group2                 3
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you!This seems to return all zeros under the Count field.  I'm adding a searchbase to narrow down the target to a few test cases.

It looks like the "allMemberOf.Count" is unique to the Quest variant "get-Qadgroup".

I changed line 6 to invoke "Get-qADGroup" and low-and-behold it works.  Thank You!